# C++, Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type

Tags: c++

So I have this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float S, Y, P;
    printf("Sisestage laenusumma eurodes:\n");
    scanf("%f", &S);
    printf("Sisestage laenuperiood aastades:\n");
    scanf("%f", &Y);
    printf("Sisestage intressim44r protsentides:\n");
    scanf("%f", &P);
    float K, T;
    K = (S * (P / 100 / 12)) / (1 - (1 + (P / 100 / 12)) ^ (-Y * 12));
    T = K * Y * 12;
    printf("Laenusummaga %.2f eurot %.2f intressim44raga te peate maksma %.2f eurot kuus %.2f aastat. Ja kokku maksate pangale %.2f eurot.", S, P, K, Y, T);
    scanf("%f", &S);
}
```

(The language in the brackets is estonian, if anyone is curious about that)

Now my problem is, on the line
`K = (S * (P / 100 / 12)) / (1 - (1 + (P / 100 / 12)) ^ (-Y * 12));` there is an error under the 1st '1' and under the '('  just  before -Y.  The error  I got on both  of them is `expression must have integral or unscoped enum type`.

I've already seen couple of posts on these,  but I still don't understand how to fix it.

One thing that worked is changing float S, Y, P to int, but I need those to be float.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your bug  is here: `^` I don't think you wanted exclusive or. You probably wanted to pow() instead. Related to what `^` does: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-exclusive-or-operator-hat?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-exclusive-or-operator-hat?view=msvc-160)

Comment: One thing that helps to debug in these cases is to break expressions down into multiple assignments.  It's annoying, but it works.  So, you might use temp variables and say `float temp = (P / 100 / 12)`, `float temp2 = (P / 100 / 12)`, and so on, finally combining the temp variables.  That will show you which expression has the error.

Comment: Second time this question has been asked today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65453820/is-it-workable-to-convert-an-int-by-adding-0-0

Comment: @Brad: Good advise, but that might add/remove other issues though in general case (int/float conversion, order of evaluation, ...).

Comment: That should be fixed with `#include <cmath>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is for bitwise operation (xor), not power.

You might use [`std::powf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) instead.

```
K = std::powf((S * (P / 100 / 12)) / (1 - (1 + (P / 100 / 12))), -12 * Y);
```

Comment: It now tells me that namespace "std" has no member "powf".

Comment: `#include <cmath>`. and before `C++11` only `pow` version is available.